# Custom error message in message.properties

Tags: grails

I've got **Form** domain class and there is  **typeOfTransaction** property. This property is required (blank: false). I want to write custom error message for this property, if the user does not set the value, the message must be appeared.

```
com.example.domain.form.typeOfTransaction.blank = Type of transaction required
```

Above is the message, but I don't get it when I'm trying to save form with empty **typeOfTransaction** field. Instead of this message I've got default message

```
"Please select an item in the list."
```

p.s. I don't know where this default message is defined.

Comment: HTML5 has several new attributes for <form> and <input>. One of these new attributes is "required". For instance

Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required="required" />

"Please select an item in the list." is default message of reqiured field. But after removing this attribute I'm still can't get my error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the absolute name of your class you need to use the exact name of the class, including capitalization - so I'm guessing you should put:

```
    com.example.domain.Form.typeOfTransaction.blank = Type of transaction required
```

If you don't use the absolute name you don't capitalize the class name:

```
    form.typeOfTransaction.blank = Type of transaction required
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, for 1.3.7 it should be in grails-app/i18n/messages.properties (or one of the language specific variants if appropriate).  I assume 2.0 would use the same location.

Comment: That's not what he's asking.  The system is generating the "Please select..." message but it is no where in the property files.